How to run hybrid MPI and openmp program in Slurm using salloc
How to run hybrid MPI and openmp program in Slurm using salloc, that can
specify number of cpus and number of openmp threads using the command: salloc ?

Typically, you would sepcify the number of tasks (which are equivalent to MPI processes in Slurm) using the --ntasks  and --ntasks-per-node options (or --nodes and --ntasks-per-node in the node-exclusive case) and then use the --cpus-per-task option to specify a stride between tasks to make space for the OpenMP threads. (You may also need options to do with reserving memory but that is dependent on how Slurm is set up on the system you are using, consult local documentation or ask the service desk.) Once you have got the resource allocation from salloc you then set OMP_NUM_THREADS in the usual way and, assuming MPI is compiled with Slurm support, launch using srun. Note: in recent versions of Slurm, the --cpus-per-task option is not propagated from salloc to srun so you need to set the SRUN_CPUS_PER_TASK environment variable to make this happen.
Concrete example: 512 MPI processes in total, 4 OpenMP threads per MPI process. Split evenly across nodes that have 128 cores (so, 16 nodes with 32 MPI processes per node). Note, this is a minimal example, you may well need other options to salloc to specify partition/QoS/account but they will depend on the local system you are using.
prompt> salloc --nodes=16 --ntasks-per-node=32 --cpus-per-task=4

salloc: Pending job allocation 6434425
salloc: job 6434425 queued and waiting for resources
salloc: job 6434425 has been allocated resources
salloc: Granted job allocation 6434425
salloc: Waiting for resource configuration
salloc: Nodes nid[001328-001329,001378,001382] are ready for job

prompt> export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK
prompt> export SRUN_CPUS_PER_TASK=$SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK

prompt> srun /path/to/my/program.x

prompt> exit
salloc: Relinquishing job allocation 6434425

Depending on local Slurm config you may need additional options such as --hint=nomultithread to place only on physical cores.
The UK National Supercomputing Service, ARCHER2 has a page describing all these options, including how to use salloc on their system. Some of the options are specific to their setup but a lot of the information is generally useful. See:
https://docs.archer2.ac.uk/user-guide/scheduler/

In the concrete example,  may we just directly order  128 cores, --ntasks-per-node=128, instead of --ntasks-per-node=32 --cpus-per-task=4. Then, we may only need to run mpi instead of hybrid mpi/openmp.  In this situation, I am not so sure how to which option is better? Do we really need to use hybrid mpi/openmp, or just plain mpi?

Your question asked about using MPI+OpenMP so that is what I answered. If you want pure MPI  with 128 MPI processes per node you could specify 128 tasks-per-node and 1 cpu-per-task

Thanks.  This helps me a lot. I will use these two options MPI+OpenMP or pure MPI to test the performance difference.
